# Preg_Replace with function does not work

Tags: php, preg-replace

can someone explain to me why this function doesn't return the user tagged id?

```
function userid($name){ 
    $a_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE tag='$name' ") or die( mysql_error()); 
    $a_id= mysql_result($a_sql ,0,"id"); 
    return $a_id;  
    } 

$text= $_POST["text"]; 
$text = preg_replace('/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/e', htmlspecialchars(userid('$1')), $text);
```

Why does this method not work?

Comment: What is `(userid('$1')` ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `preg_replace()` use `preg_replace_callback()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

This allows you to pass a function where the *replacement* parameter typically goes.

---

As a side note, please do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use [MySQLi or PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) with prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the whole second parameter to evaluate the result as php:

```
$text = preg_replace('/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/e', 'htmlspecialchars(userid($1))', $text);
```

What you are doing, is calling the functions `htmlspecialchars` and `userid` and feeding the result of that to `preg_replace`.